# Teradata Failing to Convert Date String to a Numeric value

Tags: teradata

I searched stackoverflow and on the internet but I could not find the exact answer. You can see my query below. I cannot figure out why I am getting the error message A character string failed conversion to a numeric value. I came to the conclusion it is that line of code because when I comment it out I don't get that error message but a different one. What I get instead is no more spool space which to me would make sense.

```
SELECT a.store_nbr AS club_number, a.visit_date, count(transaction_id)
FROM table_one
WHERE division = 1
  AND a.visit_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-02-01
```

Comment: What happens if you date literals - `DATE '2020-01-01` and DATE '2020-02-01'`.

Comment: Implicit conversion from string to DATE for the comparison will use the FORMAT defined for the column. Best is what @Andrew suggests - use standard date literals when supplying a literal date. Alternatives are to use CAST or TO_DATE with an explicit format, or to be sure the string format matches the column format - either change the string or ALTER the column.

Comment: It kind of worked. I can't figure out what is going on. I don't get an error message now but now I am getting a bunch of data outside of the date range. I will keep playing around with it